# Google I/O 2015 page like transition animations

Tags: angularjs, animation, angular-ui-router, material-design, angular-material

recently I really like [Google I/O 2015 event page](https://events.google.com/io2015/), especially those transition animations between different states. I know they used [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) for that, but I'm trying to recreate such delayed animations in Angular (1.4.1) and Angular-material and ui-router.

Basically what I want to achieve is this workflow:

1. before state change, animate leaving components of the app
2. leave some basic structure of the app (some basic holder containers)
3. make state change - resolve resources (REST API call)
4. transition to new state, with basic app structure (holders)
5. animate entering elements (with different delays)

This is not trivial task, and ng-animate is not very helpful, but I want to use is as much as possible. One drawback is, that leaving css classes are not added, before promises are resolved, the other it, that at one moment, both - old and new state view are present on the page.

I tried to create this directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('climbguide')
        .directive('cgAnimateElement', cgAnimateElement);

    /* @ngInject */
    function cgAnimateElement($animate, $rootScope, $state) {
        return {
            restrict:         'A',
            link:             linkFunc
        };

        function linkFunc(scope, el) {
            $animate.enter(el, el.parent());

            var cleanUp = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                function(event, toState, toParams) {
                    if ($rootScope.stateChangeBypass) {
                        $rootScope.stateChangeBypass = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var promise = $animate.leave(el);

                    promise.then(function() {
                        $rootScope.stateChangeBypass = true;
                        $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
                    });

                });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                cleanUp();
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

It basically does what I want, however for some reason it is only possible to use it one element - I assume because of the $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart') and later use of $state.go(toState.name, toParams);.

I also found two other solutions,

1. **angular-ui-router-in-out**, which uses CSS, but there is waiting for promises to be resolved before any animation happens (the loader animation would be necessary)
2. **angular-gsapify-router**, which uses javascript animations, and has the same problem as above one.

I'm still only learning angular, so I really don't know how to do this in a right way. Do you have any ideas? Thanks a lot.

P.S.: sorry for missing links to the libraries, but this is my first post to SO, so I can only post 2 links :)

Comment: To resolve the problem of having to wait for promises to be resolved why not load the data sooner - higher up the chain. You could even split the data in to that which is required for the initial transition and load the rest afterwards. To do this in a simple way I usually use abstract parent states. As the author of the two libraries you mention feel free to ask me over in Github issues.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help somebody, but I got it to work with probably dirty hack, but anyway it does, what I described in the original post.

I changed the directive so it can be re-used more times:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('climbguide')
        .directive('cgAnimateElement', cgAnimateElement);

    /* @ngInject */
    function cgAnimateElement($animate, delayedRouterService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link:     linkFunc
        };

        function linkFunc(scope, el) {

            var stateChangeBypass = false;
            $animate.enter(el, el.parent());

            // Use scope instead of $rootScope, so there is no need to de-register listener
            scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                function(event, toState, toParams) {
                    if (stateChangeBypass) {
                        // Resuming transition to the next state broadcasts new $stateChangeStart
                        // event, so it necessary to bypass it
                        stateChangeBypass = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    delayedRouterService.holdStateChange(event);
                    var promise = $animate.leave(el);
                    promise.then(function() {
                        stateChangeBypass = true;
                        delayedRouterService.releaseStateChange(toState, toParams);
                    });
                });
        }

    }

})();
```

I created service for handling state changes - preventing and resuming state changes in ui-router:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('climbguide')
        .factory('delayedRouterService', delayedRouterService);

    /* @ngInject */
    function delayedRouterService($state) {

        var _runningAnimations = 0;

        /**
         * Public methods
         *
         */
        var service = {
            holdStateChange:    holdStateChange,
            releaseStateChange: releaseStateChange
        };

        return service;
        //////////////

        /**
         * Prevent state change from the first animation
         * Store the number of currently running animations
         *
         * @param event
         */
        function holdStateChange(event) {
            if (_runningAnimations === 0) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            _runningAnimations++;
        }

        /**
         * Remove animation from the stack after it is finished
         * Resume state transition after last animation is finished
         *
         * @param toState
         * @param toParams
         */
        function releaseStateChange(toState, toParams) {
            _runningAnimations--;

            if (_runningAnimations === 0) {
                $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
            }
        }

    }
})();
```

So it's possible to use it in the HTML for the element which I want to animate

```
<div class="main" cg-animate-element>
    ...
</div>
```

And the final CSS:

```
.main {
    &.ng-animate {
        transition: opacity, transform;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
    }

    &.ng-enter {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
    }

    &.ng-enter-active {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    &.ng-leave {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    &.ng-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work on this! I am thinking about creating a decorator for the `ui-view` directive based on this, so you can indicate that its child elements should be animated when transitioning. That, combined with nested states, could lead to some really cool UI. Find me on GitHub if you're interested in collaborating.